# Validación de wsdl en Eclipse

Tags: java, apache, webservice, eclipse

Estoy tratando de validar un *wsdl sobre Eclipse Mars con el WSDLAnalyzer,* al abrir el archivo me aparece un Warnign en la primera línea *(Prologo xml)*, y me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

```
   WS-I: A problem occured while running the WS-I WSDL conformance check: 
         org.eclipse.wst.wsi.internal.analyzer.WSIAnalyzerException: null. 

-- Nested exception is: 
 java.lang.NullPointerException The WSDLAnalyzer was unable to validate the given WSDL File.
```

Alguna sugerencia..?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse y sus editores no son muy buenos validando si un xml es `bien formado` y `válido`. Para ello te recomiendo usar [XMLSpy](https://www.altova.com/es/xmlspy-xml-editor). Esto lo recomiendo porque el error no parece del wsdl sino del analizador.